# Particle filter in ROS

Tags: ros, navigation, localilzation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for particle filter implementation in ROS to use in mobile robot localization, but it seems the only available package is [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) (Adaptive Monte Carlo), I'm not sure is it possible to use it as particle filter or not, and if it's feasible, how?

**Note:** The robot (wheeled robot) provides odometry data and another data source is `Kinect`, that provides visual odometry data using [fovis](http://wiki.ros.org/fovis).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102031/particle-filter-in-ros/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-11-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way to do it is with [bfl (the Bayesian Filtering Library)](http://wiki.ros.org/bfl)which is part of the Orocos project and bundled with ROS.  This is what packages like [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf?distro=hydro) use at their core.  They even provide examples of how to write a particle filter for a mobile robot in their [getting started guide](http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/%7Etdelaet/bfl_doc/getting_started_guide/).

I have used this library directly when pre-existing nodes don't quite provide what I want  with very little trouble.  Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6